# How to create an element with javascript and then access its id on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating new `<span>` inside a `<div id="boxclass"></div>` with jQuery
like this:

```
$("#boxclass").append("<span id='test'></span>");
```

But I cant access the newly created spans on click.

```
$( "#test" ).click(function() {

    alert("Clicked on appended span");

});
```

How can i solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you execute your listener AFTER the append? the $("#test") is executed BEFORE the append, they are not related and it doesnt work

Comment: I added a listener after the main <div> and it worked: `document.getElementById("boxclass").addEventListener("click", function)`
Thank you.

Comment: I usually create a addListenerFunction(){$("#test").click().....} and called after the append. If you do in this way remember to remove the listener if added, or the code will execute twice